# Text deformed in rotated div in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, transform, rotatetransform

I have a page where content rotates into view.

```
<div id="viewport">
    <div id="pages">
        <div id="page1" class="page">
            Page 1
        </div>
            ...
        <div id="page6" class="page">
            Page 6
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in css

```
 body{
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif; //google web font
 }
 #viewport{
    width: 700px;
    height: 446px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#pages{
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    left: -716px;
    position: relative;
    width: 2094px;
    height: 2010px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#page1 {
    left: 717px;
}
#page2 {
    top: 414px;
    left: 1435px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(60deg);
}
```

and I rotate the #pages div. This works fine in for example firefox (with the appropriate browser properties). But in Chrome (28.0.1500.20 beta-m and 26something, both on 64bit windows 7) the font is deformed [google drive link to example](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-PgY7MFRf4-Z0Zzc2FzV1V1SXc/edit?usp=drivesdk). I didn't find it in the chrome issue tracker. Am I doing something wrong or should I file a bug report? Thanks for any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

OK found a fix

```
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
```

was what I was looking for. Still doesn't look as good as in ff but it at least stays in one line.